# decrypt passwords in database stored in hash code

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, nosql

I wonder is there any way to decrypt passwords in `sql` database in an clear plain text that which already stored in `HASH code`?? if so can anyone explain me.

Thank you.

Comment: No, you can't. That's the purpose of hashes. To be *one way*.

Comment: why can't admin should not see that.. i wonder

Comment: Why you should see others password? Let them reset.

Comment: there are several purposes to see.. resetting not an only option i seen two years ago i recovered my way2sms password as it is.. that's thing i should know

Comment: Depends on the hash. We use $200 powerful but unwanted GPUs to generate more than 225 million hashes per second, and with known prefixes and rainbow tables, Olypus has fallen

Comment: What do you like to achieve? Transferring a password from one DB to another? For this you can simply copy the hash value.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the hashing algorithm used, but given that it's hashed at all, then a [one way function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) has almost certainly been used, which means you can't decrypt it easily.

Comment: Oh.. Thats may be happen.. but you told **not easily**